# Move DirectX window from one monitor to another in extended mode

Tags: c++, directx, directx-9

I have a simple directX-9 test app that I want to move from one monitor to another in extended mode.
The window and the device are created on the primary monitor and scene is drawn correctly but when I move my window to the second monitor it will freeze. There is no error and even the present calls do not fail but there is no update of the window. As soon as I move the window back to the primary monitor everything is fine again.
Can anyone give me a hint what am I missing to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to enumerate over your adapter modes. The mode you are using might have a problem with the graphics card. Also, for each format that an adapter supports there is a list of display modes based on the number of modes available. Here's a quick example of looping through these modes:

```
D3DDISPLAYMODE mode;
UINT adapter = 0;
D3DFORMAT format = D3DFMT_R5G6B5;
LPDIRECT3D9 pD3D;

pD3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION );

if(!pD3D) return FALSE;

UINT availableModes = pD3D->GetAdapterModeCount(Adapter, Format);

if(!availableModes) return FALSE;

for(UINT i = 0; i < availableModes; i++)
{
    pD3D->EnumAdapterModes( adapter, format, i, &mode);
    formatModeList->push_back(mode); // A list of modes
}
```

Also, make sure you are NOT using flipping if you are in windowed mode. In windowed mode, you share the current video mode of the applications running. Unfortunately, you have to use the slower blitting process. Hopefully this helps.

Regards,

Will

Comment: That already helped me, but still I have no clue how to find out that my window changed the monitor. If I add a button to my App I can force the recreation of the device for the second adapter and everything works as expected. But to detect the monitor change?

Comment: @mkaes, Just to confirm, are you are checking for a lost device? I'm not sure why going to the second monitor would cause a lost device but before looking into it any further I just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes I did. But neither the present on the swap chain nor a TestCooperativeLevel returned a device lost. Only S_OK. I have also seen that VLC can display a video with directX on both monitors partially at the same time. So I have an even bigger issue :-(

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was the D3DPRESENTFLAG_DEVICECLIP flag that was specified. Removing this flag and I can move from on monitor to another without any issue. Still I am wondering if there is a way to determine that the monitor has changed.